# Kentico Universal Pager update panel

Tags: kentico

I have a Pages data source, repeater, and universal pager. All is working, but i'm trying to avoid a QueryString and page reload.

I've set the universal pager to Post back, but that still forces a page reload. Checking Use update panel as well, changes the pagination states, but doesn't actually change the pages.

Is there another setting i'm missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put all the web parts in a separate zone and set the zone to "Use update panel". Make sure the "Use update panel" setting is off for the web parts themselves though.

Comment: I have this all in a WebPartZone. So let me check the settings!

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what i was looking for. Thanks Rocky!

Comment: Glad to help ;)